# Do I need to add sourcemap preprocessor in karma even though I have devtool in webpack config

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, karma-webpack

I have karma preprocessor as

```
'preprocessors: {
  './spec/tests.webpack.js': ['webpack','sourcemap']
 },
 reporters: ['coverage-istanbul'],
 singleRun: true,
 webpack: webpackConfig'
```

And my webpackConfig has `devtool` as `inline-source-map`. Even when I remove the sourcemap from karma preprocessor, I am still able to see the source files mapped. What exactly does the karma sourcemap preprocessor do?

Here is my complete karma config

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var chai = require('chai')
var chaiAspromised = require('chai-as-promised')
var sinonChai = require('sinon-chai')
var webpackConfig = require('../webpack.config');

module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({
 browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
files: [
  './spec/tests.webpack.js',
  './../node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon.js'

],
frameworks: ['jasmine','chai'],
preprocessors: {
  './spec/tests.webpack.js': ['webpack','sourcemap']
},
 reporters: ['coverage-istanbul'],
 singleRun: true,
 webpack: webpackConfig,
 webpackServer: {
  noInfo: true,
 }
});
};
```

And my webpack config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
 entry: './app/bootstrapper.js',
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    library: 'EntryPoint'
 },

module: {
    rules: 
      [ 
    //     {
    //         test: /\.js$/,
    //         exclude: /\.test.js$|\.spec.js$|node_modules/,
    //         use: [
    //         'babel-loader',
    //             {
    //                 loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
    //                 options: {
    //                 esModules: true
    //                 }
    //             }
    //         ]
    //   },
    //   {
    //         test: /\.js$/,
    //         exclude: /node_modules/,
    //         loader: 'babel-loader'
    //   },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'ng-annotate-loader?add=true!babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /.html$/,
            loader: 'ngtemplate-loader?relativeTo=' + __dirname +'/app!html?
        root=' + __dirname + '/app'
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{loader: 'style-loader'},{loader: 'css-loader?root=' + 
        __dirname + '/app'},{loader: 'sass-loader'},{loader: 'autoprefixer-
        loader?browsers=last 2 versions'}]
        },
        { 
            test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' 
        },
        { 
            test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|gif)$/, loader: 'url-
           loader?limit=100000' 
        },
        {
            test: /\.png$/,
            loader: 'file-loader'
        }]
       },
       plugins: [
       // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true, output: { 
        comments: false }}),
       new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
      })
      ],
     resolve: {
       modules: [path.resolve('app/'),
         path.resolve('node_modules/')]
     },
     devtool: 'inline-source-map' 
     };
```

Comment: Can you post your `karma.conf.js` and your test webpack config?

Comment: add both config files